# Sun Rotation and Texture Swapping

Tags: texturing, drivers, npr

Hey I was looking into a bit of npr and was wondering if there was a way to swap out image textures based on the current rotation of the sun. I haven't studied blender drivers like that so if possible How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Hello, could you add a bit more information about your current setup so it's easier to find a solution ? Thanks

Comment: Hi, Rocket. By 'the sun' do you mean a Sun Lamp, somewhere in the scene? Please illustrate with, at least, a toy example

Comment: So right now i have a sun lamp and a character with a toon shader in the scene i want to swap either normal maps or base color image textures based on the sun lamps  rotation.